# Taking in two Int's through textField randomize

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am trying to take two Int's inside text fields then randomly pick a number between the minimum value and the maximum value then put that randomized number into a Label that updates a timer.

This code does have errors

I think I'm overthinking this however I cant find anything that has helped me so far. Thanks in advance.

```
@IBAction func randomizeButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    minValueNum = Int.random(in: 1...60)
    maxValueNum = Int.random(in: 1...60)
    
    randomValue = Int()
    if maxValueNum < minValueNum {
        timerLabel.text = "Error"
    } else {
        minValueNum > maxValueNum {
            timerLabel.text = "Error"
        } else {
            minValueNum < maxValueNum {
                timerlabel.text = minTextField + maxTextField
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Your description and the code seems to be about tow different things. Where do you get the values from the text fields for instance? Right now you seem to generate them in code instead. And what is your actual question?

Comment: I have 2 IBOutlets one for minTextField and the other for maxTextField that you type a number into then click the randomize button to take those two numbers and randomize from the minimum number up to the maximum number. Thats what I am trying to do.

Comment: But that has nothing to do with your posted code! This looks more like a request to have someone write the code for you than an actual question,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you are missing some `if` keywords. Here's a long iteration of changes to fix your code:

Step 1: Add the missing `if` keywords

```
@IBAction func randomizeButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    minValueNum = Int.random(in: 1...60)
    maxValueNum = Int.random(in: 1...60)
    
    randomValue = Int()
    if maxValueNum < minValueNum {
        timerLabel.text = "Error"
    } else {
        if minValueNum > maxValueNum { // Add if here
            timerLabel.text = "Error"
        } else {
             if minValueNum < maxValueNum { // Add if here
                timerlabel.text = minTextField + maxTextField
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Step 2: learn about `else if` and your code becomes:

```
@IBAction func randomizeButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    minValueNum = Int.random(in: 1...60)
    maxValueNum = Int.random(in: 1...60)
    
    randomValue = Int()
    if maxValueNum < minValueNum {
        timerLabel.text = "Error"
    } else if minValueNum > maxValueNum {
        timerLabel.text = "Error"
    } else if minValueNum < maxValueNum {
        timerlabel.text = minTextField + maxTextField
    }
}
```

Step 3: the first two `if` comparisons are identical so you remove one:

```
@IBAction func randomizeButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    minValueNum = Int.random(in: 1...60)
    maxValueNum = Int.random(in: 1...60)
    
    randomValue = Int()
    if minValueNum > maxValueNum {
        timerLabel.text = "Error"
    } else if minValueNum < maxValueNum {
        timerlabel.text = minTextField + maxTextField
    }
}
```

Step 4: But what if min and max are the same? You are ignoring that.

```
@IBAction func randomizeButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    minValueNum = Int.random(in: 1...60)
    maxValueNum = Int.random(in: 1...60)
    
    randomValue = Int()
    if minValueNum >= maxValueNum { // Change > to >=
        timerLabel.text = "Error"
    } else if minValueNum < maxValueNum {
        timerlabel.text = minTextField + maxTextField
    }
}
```

Step 5: now the `else if` check is redundant since if the first `if` isn't true we know that min must be less than max.

```
@IBAction func randomizeButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    minValueNum = Int.random(in: 1...60)
    maxValueNum = Int.random(in: 1...60)
    
    randomValue = Int()
    if minValueNum >= maxValueNum {
        timerLabel.text = "Error"
    } else { // Remove redundant check
        timerlabel.text = minTextField + maxTextField
    }
}
```

---

OK, that long walkthrough shows how to fix your logic. But now we need to address the real issues. You make no attempt to get the numbers from the text fields and use those values to generate the random number.

The following code makes use of the text field entries.

```
@IBAction func randomizeButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // Attempt to get the min and max from the text fields
    guard let minValueNum = Int(minTextField.text!),
          let maxValueNum = Int(maxTextField.text!)
        else {
        timerLabel.text = "Error"
        return
    }
    
    if minValueNum >= maxValueNum {
        timerLabel.text = "Error"
    } else {
        // Generate the random number within the entered range
        let randomNumber = Int.random(in: minValueNum...maxValueNum)
        timerlabel.text = "\(randomNumber)"
    }
}
```

The `guard` ensures that the user entered valid numbers into the text fields.

This also removes the `randomValue = Int()` line which wasn't even being used. And instead of adding the min and max values, it generates a random number between min and max.

FYI - force-unwrapping the `text` property of `UITextField` is always safe. Even if `nil`, you will get back the empty string (`""`).

Comment: thank you for looking at my code and giving corrections and explanation for the changes, I was struggling with this for hours and trying a few other larger code blocks that didn't work. Much Appreciated!

Comment: Well done. (voted) You did a good job figuring out what the OP was trying to do, and then patiently outlined the steps needed to achieve that goal.